# Can I get around Acer BIOS password bug (suposed) with different model BIOS update?

Tags: boot, laptop, bios, passwords

while setting up linux to dual boot, I was required to set a supervisor password and surprise surprise I used my master password that I use for important things. However, when I needed to get back into BIOS (I have full access to windows) I could not, the password and any imaginable combination didn't work. I finally stumbled on a thread where this seems to be an Acer specific problem to the Swift 3 model laptops. Neither Acer's unlock code when I called in or the one generated by bios-pw generator work. I've also taken out the CMOS battery for some time and it did not help.

Thread: https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/544886/swift-3-bios-password-after-upgrade?fbclid=IwAR3xBWbxTu5YZVzcpE7vYXnMeFSpnaAFhDTY4sqjA4-moVFyCNF52UYSgUI

However, the BIOS update they put up is for the SF315-52 (i7) and I have the SF315-51 (i5). The only difference I could discern was the processor.

My question is, would it be possible to use the available BIOS update with my laptop?

Answer (score 1):

Using a BIOS not specifically designed for your machine can permanently break it. I ***highly*** recommend against it. Contact Acer support to see what the proper method of fixing your BIOS is. It is far smarter to wait and do things correctly, than brick your machine.